# MySQL AND & OR operator

Tags: mysql

What is an operator in MySQL queries that covers AND and OR. So if I wanted to select a row where value1=lol OR value2=loly or both do.

Comment: `OR` by itself does that. Are you confusing it with `XOR`? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html

Comment: Also, parenthesis will help context of the `OR`.

Comment: `OR` executes when either condition is true ***and*** when both conditions are true. `AND` only executes when ***both*** conditions are true. `XOR` executes when either condition is true but ***not*** when both are true.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Oh, I see. I didn't quite understand how each operator worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will look for one of the values or both.

```
    SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE your_column IN ( 'lol','loly' )
```

Answer (score 1):

With a query with the OR it'll work:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_field = 'lol' OR my_field = 'loly'
```

it'll give you all the results with the first or the second

As an extra, I think you could be looking for `WHERE` with regular expressions: Check this manual page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this wasn't a very good question.

I now understand that the OR operator will work with either condition met, or both.

AND only works with both.

XOR works with either one but not both.

Credit goes to the comments replying to my question.